# Word.Shape.Name taking maximum 18 characters

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Word.Interop library. If I assign less than 18 characters to 'Word.Shape.Name' then it work perfect but when I assign more than 18 characters then 'Word.Shape.Name' throw exception. 
e.g

```
Word.Shape.Name = "This is a test value to assign";
```

throw exception

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException:    Access is denied.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".

What I should do to resolve this problem?
Whole method is

```
 objTargetDocument, ref Scripting.Dictionary dicMarkers, ref Alias.Document objSourceDocument)
    {
        bool blnRetVal = false;
        string strModel = ndModel.Name;
        int lngModel = 0;
        int lngNextModel = 0;
        int lngStart;
        int lngEnd;
        Alias.Document objTemp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range objRange;
        Shape objShape;
        Object[] astr;
        int n;
        bool bLastModel;
        /*'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   1. Find model's model marker and the next marker (if any)
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        astr = dicMarkers.Keys();
        for (n = astr.GetLowerBound(0); n <= astr.GetUpperBound(0); n++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(astr[n].ToString(), strModel, true) == 0)
            {
                lngModel = (int)dicMarkers.get_Item(astr[n]);   //PNDC  //dicMarkers.Item(astr(n))
                if (n < astr.GetUpperBound(0))
                {
                    if (string.Compare(astr[n + 1].ToString(), "#end", true) == 0)
                    {
                        lngNextModel = 0;
                        bLastModel = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lngNextModel = (int)dicMarkers.get_Item(astr[n + 1]);
                        bLastModel = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lngNextModel = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        /*'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   2. Copy model from original document to new document
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        if (lngModel > 0)
        {
            lngStart = objSourceDocument.Sections[lngModel].Range.Start;
            if (lngNextModel == 0)
            {
                var key = "#end";
                var value = dicMarkers.get_Item(key);
                lngEnd = value;
            }
            else
                lngEnd = objSourceDocument.Sections[lngNextModel].Range.Start; //objSourceDocument.Sections.Last.Index;

            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //copy original
            objSourceDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.SetRange(lngStart, lngEnd);
            objSourceDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            bool bInsertSection = false;
            //paste (append) copied model to the document
            if (objTargetDocument.Sections.First.Index == objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.Index)
            {
                //Target document only has 1 (default) section
                bInsertSection = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.PageSetup.SectionStart == WdSectionStart.wdSectionNewPage)
                {
                    //Last section is a nextpage section
                    if ((objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.Range.End - (objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.Range.Start) <= 1))
                        //Empty section
                        bInsertSection = false;
                    else
                        bInsertSection = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Last section isn't a nextpage
                    bInsertSection = true;
                }

            }

            objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Start = objTargetDocument.Range().End;
            if (bInsertSection)
            {
                objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
                objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Start = objTargetDocument.Range().End;
            }

            objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Collapse();
            objRange = objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Duplicate; //remember range for model marker anchor
            objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
            objTargetDocument.Variables.Add(m_strModelMarker + strModel);


            // .TextFrame.ContainingRange

            //place model marker (so that we can find our model again)
            objShape = objTargetDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationUpward, 0, 0, 0, 0, objRange);

            objShape.Name = m_strModelMarker + strModel; // This Line Trowing Exception
            objShape.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

            UpdateFields(ref objTargetDocument, ref ndModel);
            blnRetVal = true;
        }
        else
            new Modules.Globals().MsgBoxEx("Kan het bestaande model '" + strModel + "' niet kopieren.", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return blnRetVal;

    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to setting the Name property on an instance or on the type?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find any reference to a 18-character limitation in the `Name` property. Also, after a quick test, it seems to work fine (even by inputting a much longer length):

```
Word.Shape oShape = oDoc.Shapes.AddLine(0, 0, 0, 0);
oShape.Name = "This is a test value to assign - This is a test value to assign";
```

Thus, the error you are mentioning is most likely provoked by a different part of your code.

In any case, I am not sure that you understand the exact meaning of the `Name` property. This is not something you would be seeing in the Word document at all; this is something for "internal reference purposes". The `Shapes` array is actually a `Dictionary` which can be accessed by typing either the index or the name of the given shape; that is, if `oShape`, as defined above, is the first shape in the document, I can access it by using any of the folowing options:

```
Word.Shape oShape2 = oDoc.Shapes[1];
Word.Shape oShape2 = oDoc.Shapes["This is a test value to assign - This is a test value to assign"];
```

For this reason, writing too long names is not necessary anyway.

Comment: i have edit my question, now you can see whole method and Shape.Name value is "Carma DocSys~brief" in my case. "This is a test value to assign" was just supposed value.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizulqadir I cannot see any problem with your code. But, as said, writing so long names is not necessary. If you want to change the text displayed by the TextBox you would have to affect the TextFrame.TextRange.Text property of the Shape. Are you using Office 2003, it might be what shamp00 is proposing?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizulqadir I am not able to replicate this situation with Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72885a68-96c3-4146-81e7-c9bb7a83fce0/word-addin-2003-doubt) about Word 2003 which seems to be similar.

In that discussion, it suggests storing the name in a document variable object (as in `Document.Variables`).

Something like:

```
Variables vars = Doc.Variables;
var = vars.Add("myShapeName", "This is a test value to assign");
```

and then assign `var.Value` to `Word.Shape.Name` somehow.

**Edit**

On re-reading that linked discussion, there is no way of directly assigning a `Doc.Variable` to the `Name` property. What you can set the shape's `Name` to a short unique identifier and use it to retrieve your long string from the `Variables` wherever you need it.

```
void SetLongName(Shape shape, string uniqueId, string longName)
{
    shape.Name = uniqueId;
    Variables vars = Doc.Variables;
    var = vars.Add(uniqueId, longName);
}

string GetLongNameOfShape(Shape shape)
{
    return GetLongNameById(shape.Name);
}

string GetLongNameById(string uniqueId)
{
    Variables vars = Doc.Variables;
    return vars.get_Item(uniqueId).Value;
}
```